# How to get contact ID using their community user ID?

Tags: apex, trigger, class

I'm trying to create a trigger that will get the contact information based on the user ID and then based on that contact information delegate a pricebook in the Opportunity section. 
 
I've managed to get the user ID using the below line of code

```
String userName = UserInfo.getUserId();
```

the only thinng that's left to do is get the contact details based on that user. I've tried using the follwoing soql query:

```
List<User> lstUser = [Select u.ContactId from User u where u.Id = :userName];
```

and then allocating it to a string in such a way:

```
Sring contactb = 1stuser.contactID 
String brandb = contactb.Brand__c
```

but it doesn't seem to work. can anyone suggest a better, more efficient way in dealing with such problems ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out I've made the changes with no errors.

Comment: Try to use lstUser.get(0).contactId or fetch user instead  of list of users from query. See if this is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are assigning the user record to a list and below line is incorrect because list can have one or more records.Read this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm)

In this case since you are getting info of the logged in user there can only be one record so you have change it to

```
Id contactb = 1stuser[0].contactID
```

I also changed the type of contactb to ID as the info you are assigning is of type ID

Below line is incorrect because you have not queried the contact record yet so you can’t access any field values of contact.

```
String brandb = contactb.Brand__c
```

for illustration what you need to do is below(querying the contact record)

```
lst<contact> lstContactinfo = [select Id,Brand__c from Contact where Id = :contactb LIMIT 1];
```

and then i would access its value by doing String brandb = lstContactinfo[0].Brand__c

in both the cases we are instantiating contact and user information in a list so better to always have a size check before we access it

```
if(lstContactinfo.size() > 0)
```

Comment: Why? Can you add some explanation? I guess you have some in the comments but it's tucked away and requires some scrolling.

Comment: Sure will do @AdrianLarson. I will bring them over to the second line and add more explanation. sorry!

Comment: No need to apologize!